# using php preg_match,warning

Tags: php, preg-match

```
regex:^([^\/])/([A-Z])([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$
```

string to match: `http://127.0.0.1:8008/BeiJing/FangChan/`

I use preg_match() to test

```
if (preg_match('/^([^\/])/([A-Z])([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/$/',"http://127.0.0.1:8008/BeiJing/FangChan/",$match))
    print $match[0];
else
    print 'not match';
```

but get a Warning: `preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('` 
Can anyone help me write this regex so it's valid for the preg_match function? I've tried a ton of different ideas but I'm really not too knowledgeable with regex.

Comment: You should take a look at the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function probably. A good introduction to regular expressions [can be found on this website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: What is that regex _supposed_ to match? It doesn't match the URL.

Comment: It matches `a/Bc/d/` as long as B is capitalized, but it doesn't match _any_ URL. If you remove the anchors `^` and `$`, it matches `8/BeiJing/FangChan/`

Answer (score 3):

`/` is what is indicating the start and the end of the pattern in your example, whatever comes after the pattern is a modifier.

So this:

```
/^([^/])/([A-Z])([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$/
```

Gets read as this:

```
/^([^/])/
```

With modifiers `([A-Z])([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$/`

You have to escape all `/`'s  or change the start and end indicator:

```
#^([^/])/([A-Z])([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$#
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the / you use by putting a \ in front of it. Or change the first and last / to something else like:

```
if (preg_match('|^([^/])/([A-Z])([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$|',"http://127.0.0.1:8008/BeiJing/FangChan/",$match)) print $match[0]; else
```

But this regexp will not match the url.